# Set with all rows for web2py / pydal

Tags: web2py, pydal

In `web2py` I can do the following:

```
rows = db().select(person.ALL)
```

Which gives me all *rows* in the database person.

I can also do:

```
myset = db(person.name == 'Jim')
```

Which gives me a *set* of all people named `Jim`.

How can I get a *set* of **all** people?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `Set` object defining all the records in the table, you can do:

```
db(db.person)
```

which is equivalent to:

```
db(db.person.id > 0)
```

Comment: Thanks, I could not find that in the [documentation](http://pydal.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#pydal.objects.Set)